# SharePoint 2010 Upgrade Fails on Application Server but Works on Web Front Ends

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Currently we are upgrading our SharePoint 2010 Farm to SP2, the farm topology consists of 5 application and search servers and 20 Web Application servers which support 6 heavy utilized portals.

after installing the service packs on all servers, I've initiated the upgrade software on the first application server but the upgrade failed and when I checked the error log file I found that all the errors were related to missing portal solutions on the application server, so I started the upgrade on one of the web servers and it ran successfully. the question now is, do I have to install all the solutions on the application servers as well to have a successful upgrade or no need to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between application servers and web servers in SharePoint. Only difference is that some services run application servers or web servers.
You should deploy all solutions on all servers that install SharePoint server .

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? because I think this is the best practice but do I really need to?

Comment: You can find sample at following link